# Disable Cache in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

This is a problem that occurs for our IE 8 users (does not happen on IE 9).  When rendering a reporting services report IE 8 caches the report so if the data is changed and the user re-runs the report stale data is displayed until the user restarts IE or hits the refresh button.

If I set IE 8 -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Browsing History Settings -> Check for newer versions of stored pages: from "Automatically" to "Every time a I visit a webpage" the problem is fixed, however, I was wondering if there is a setting on SSRS that can tell IE 8  to request a new copy every load without changing the setting for every users's computer?

I already have "Always run this report with the most recent data" and "Do not cache temporary copies of this report" selected in SSRS for this report.

Thanks.